# Long-necked Zephyranthes bulb: How does that happen?

Tags: bulbs

That week I received my long-anticipated shipment of *Zephyranthes* and *Habranthus* bulbs.
The picture below is that of *Zephyranthes drummondii*. All bulbs were purchased while dormant and without soil.

[image: Zephyranthes drumondii]

One thing which caught my eye, is that some bulbs are larger than others, and possess a longer "neck".
One was exceptionally large and its neck is as tall as the depth of the pot in which it was placed.
The image below shows almost two-thirds of the neck above the soil.
So how does this happen? Is that a response to deeper planting (hence the long neck) which also causes the bulbs to grow larger?

I have *Zephyranthes grandiflora* (the pale purple variety) which was the only species in our possession for almost 60 years. While the bulbs multiplied and I separated them into different pots, I never saw bulbs growing much beyond the size of garlic.